# "Select in" with "ordered pairs"

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2000

I have a table structure like this.

```
ProductCR   productID   ProductName 
09          1553        A1 
09          1600        A2 
09          1800        A3
10          1553        A4 
10          1600        A5 
10          2000        A6
```

I want to make something like this:

```
Select ProductoName from Products where (ProductCR,ProductID) in ((09,1553),(10,1600),(10,2000))

Result:
    A1
    A5
    A6
```

Is this posible in Sql Server?? such a "select in" with "ordered pairs"??
Thanks,
Victor.

Comment: running this command gives you what ?

Comment: I want the records with ProductName A1,A5,A6

Comment: i was asking when you are running your query in there what it says error of kind? well Andomar's query will do it for you then.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I get an error, something like ", not expected"

Comment: yaa sql dont support it. if you desire for only these 3 in result you know query is there.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. I this this is a good option:

```
DECLARE @orderedPairs TABLE (cr int, id int)

INSERT INTO @orderedPairs (cr, id)
VALUES (09,1553),(10,1600),(10,2000)

SELECT ProductName
  FROM Products
  join @orderedPairs on ProductCR = cr
                    and ProductID = id
```

Comment: I'm new with SQL and I didnt know about the Table variable, I think I'll read about it. 
So if I do a query with this Table variable, then this table is deleted when the query is closed?

Comment: Yes. You may want to read something too about temporary tables. Sometimes is better variable tables and many other times is better temporal tables.

Comment: Note that the table variable will perform well for small amounts of data, but for large data sets the optimizer may choose a bad execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle allows that](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm), but SQL Server does not.  You'll have to write it out:

```
select  ProductoName 
from    Products 
where   ProductCR = 09 and ProductID = 1553 or
        ProductCR = 10 and ProductID = 1600 or
        ProductCR = 10 and ProductID = 2000
```

Comment: Yes I knew that Oracle allows it, I thought Sql Server would have something similar