# Using IN with multiple linked conditions - SQL

Tags: sql-server

My code currently looks like the following...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CLIENT.FIRST_NAME,
    CLIENT.LAST_NAME,
    DATE_DIM.DATE
FROM
    DW.DBO.TEST
WHERE
    CLIENT.ID1 IN (A1, A2, A3, A4, A5)
AND
    DATE_DIM.DATE IN (1/11/2015, 1/12/2015, 1/13/2015, 1/14/2015, 1/15/2015)
```

What I would like to know is there any way to link the two conditions? I.E. I don't want results where client id1 A1 is linked to 1/12/2015, because it's causing me to have to do a lot of manual editing after the output. Thank you!

Comment: Not with the `IN` operator. You can use `CLIENT.ID1 = A1 AND CLIENT.ID2 = B1) OR (CLIENT.ID1 = A2 AND CLIENT.ID2 = B2)...`

Comment: Is there a work around if I have hundreds of IDs? Or is the only solution to type it all out

Comment: If you would edit your question to provide some sample data as DDL+DML and desired results, perhaps it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7698931/3270427

Comment: Just saying that I know I can write it as (CLIENT.ID1 = A1 AND CLIENT.ID2 = B1), but what if I have A1 - A300, and B1-B300. Typing that all out is a lot of work, so just wondering if there is a workaround I am missing

Comment: Arjun it is entirely possible. But your question is vague all we can do is speculate. I can think of several different ideas here but it all depends on what the actual details are. If you post those details you will find lots of great ideas of how to solve this. If you don't post details...well...you are pretty much on your own because we don't have the information needed to help.

Comment: @SeanLange -- seriously?  this is clearly a join to a table of tuples -- a basic SQL pattern -- why make it out like a mystery?

Comment: @Hogan Im with Sean here, I can guess are tuples but we shouldnt have to "guess".

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza -- I don't think there is any guessing to know that is what Arjus in asking.

Comment: @Hogan Maybe if you use the comments, but with only the question you cant know.

Comment: *is there any way to link the two conditions?* <= seems clear.

Comment: @Hogan glad you were able to make out what they wanted. It was not at all apparent to me from the original post what they were trying to do.

Comment: @SeanLange -- another 5 years on stackoverflow and you will be able to read the posters "minds" as well as I do. :D

Comment: @SeanLange -- To be clear, I agree that his question can be clearer.  But I think an obnoxious link and a 5 sentence berating was to much.  One comment pointing to the FAQ how to ask a question is probably fine.  Better is to re-write the question.

Comment: @Hogan Not sure what you mean about an obnoxious link or a berating. I was trying to explain why it is important to provide details. And as far as posting on forums I have been doing this a long time too just not on SO as much as some people. :)

Comment: @SeanLange -- just my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is easy just put it in a table or make one on the fly

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CLIENT.FIRST_NAME,
    CLIENT.LAST_NAME,
    DATE_DIM.DATE
FROM DW.DBO.TEST
JOIN CLIENT -- you didn't include this part
JOIN DATE_DIM -- you didn't include this part
JOIN (
   SELECT 'A1', '1/11/2015'
    UNION ALL
   SELECT 'A2', '1/12/2015'
    UNION ALL
   SELECT 'A3', '1/13/2015'
    UNION ALL
   SELECT 'A4', '1/14/2015'
    UNION ALL
   SELECT 'A5', '1/15/2015'
) AS TMP(ID, D) ON CLIENT.ID1 = TMP.ID AND DATE_DIM.DATE = TMP.D
```

> I fixed up your code a little since you included TABLES you did not define and illegal constants -- I just made everything a string for this example.

---

Some platforms (DB2 and Oracle - I know for sure) you can use tuples in the IN clause.... that looks like this:

```
WHERE (CLIENT.ID, DATE_DIM) IN ( -- list of tuples here or select statement)
```

Comment: You're welcome @ArjunArun -- remember if this answers you question you should up vote it and accept it -- on stackoverflow this is more important than saying thank you for users of the site.